# Not sure what to make of this wiki-style question on penetrating oils

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question in question:

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/21140/675

I'm not sure how good a fit this type of question is for the following reasons:

- it refers to specific brands
- it attempts to categorize products by geography (locations where they're available)
- any brand that is relevant today could be irrelevant tomorrow
- the Q&A format doesn't work too well here (those who remember community wiki style questions from Stack Overflow a few years back)

Answer (score 6):

If I weren't a mod, I would flag this as too broad (if I flag it, it'll immediately close so pretend I did).

Obvious problem is: where is the question?  What penetrating oils are available in my area?  Just type that into Google and let their smartness figure it out for you.

If the question was something like "what is the difference between penetrating oil and oil that I'd want to use as a lubricant?", this would be an entirely different thing. I'd love to know that answer. ;-)

Comment: As to the last part of that statement, Mr. Smarty Pants, I bet you already ***DO*** know the answer to that question ... ;-)

Comment: Actually I don't know much about oil formulations. Always learning!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this to be off topic as well. I know on other sites list questions are off topic. I don't see an issue with those being off topic here either. One thing to think about is that it is too broad as @BobCross said. Another thing to think about is any information could change if a company goes out of business. To me, that makes it no better than a shopping question.

- The information is going to be too volatile for it to remain valid.
- Also, who's going to add to it as things change?
- Do we edit the original post?
- Do we just add another answer?
- How is there going to be one right answer?

I am going to vote to close it as well ... I just haven't decided as to *how* I want to mark the close vote.

Comment: I marked my closed vote as *off-topic* with explanation. It really isn't a good fit for the site in my approximation.

Answer (score 2):

He stated specifically he wants to compile a list of penetrating oils. This is a case where even though his intentions are good the thread is wildly inappropriate for the format of this site. OP could make a list on any wiki or in a spreadsheet on his own computer.

Answer (score 1):

I am the original author. The question came about as I have been removing the rear suspension on a 10 year old vehicle (get your friends to persuade you to never do this if you start thinking about it ;-)

The bolts were mostly seized and on the forums I frequent the recommendations were for Kroil Oil - which is not available where I live. Further googling/forum-scanning produced a variety of names and I eventually bought something, which seems to have had very limited effect making any nuts easier to remove, even after multiple applications.

So this is how the question came about.

The primary concern with the question seems to be that it is a 'list' question, so:

- who is going to maintain it?
- there is no 'right' answer

I'm happy to maintain it - I doubt that the products will change very frequently. But of course there is no 'right' answer - my only feeling at present is that Kroil Oil seems to be much more highly regarded than other products.

Maybe the question can be phrased differently? But I'm OK to have it closed - I just wanted to have a source that I could refer to and make public rather than just a 'I used it and it seemed OK' experience.

Comment: We've had a few questions on here regarding alternative chemicals. There is one regarding [alternatives to Seafoam](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/16486/675), which turned out to be quite a nice addition to the mech.SE community. I'm trying to think of how you could alter the question to make it a better fit. There can be a fine line between a great question and an unsuitable one.

Comment: Why don't you just ask for a substitute for Kroil Oil, as you have mentioned in this post? Mention what you're doing with the rest suspension to give some backdrop and you should be golden in my opinion

Comment: I think a better question would be: how to remove this tough bolt?